# SharePoint Store : adding DocuSign app to a site via REST API in Power Automate

Tags: rest, docusignapi, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a Power Automate flow in which I try to install the App **DocuSign** in a new site collection among the existing Apps in it.

I know there are endpoints/methods that install **.SPPKG** or **.APP packages** in the site. However I didn't find the one that installs any App from the SharePoint Store.
So, I need some help to find the correct REST API query to add **DocuSign** from it.

I tried something similar too with the following query but it only works for any installed app (identified by its GUID) in the tenant:

```
POST | _api/Web/TenantAppCatalog/AvailableApps/GetById('eeffc457-6f7f-46b9-adcb-165999799ed2')/Install
```

This query adds the app named *Custom Learning for Office 365* that was installed by default in my tenant.

I tried to track all HTTP requests via Fiddler too, but no results.
I run out of ideas.

Can someone show me how to install an app from the SP store via a REST API endpoint please?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of feature is not provided by DocuSign API. You may need to contact the Microsoft Sharepoint team for further information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell to run a script that install SPO apps in SharePoint sites.
this can be done from PowerAutomate, here is a link of how to do that:

https://practical365.com/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-to-automate-manual-processes-in-office-365/